# Find symmetry along line

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider line $L:(1,0,3)+t(2,2,1)$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ find formula for symmetry along line $L$

I'd be greatful if anyone can describe the method how to approach this

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetry along line"?

Comment: sorry it's not precise, should be symmetry along $L^{\perp}$